# Jquery causes slowness after submitting form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

We have this jquery function that submits the form at the click of the button. Remember that the button is type submit.

```
  $("#btn-modal-confirm-Restart").click(function () {
    var included = 0;

    $('.icheck').each(function () {

        var index = $(this).data('row-index');
        var isIncludedCheckBox = $('#Items_' + index + '__IsIncluded');

        if (isIncludedCheckBox.is(':checked')) {
            included++;
        }
    });

    if (included === 0) {
        $('#confirmation-modal').modal('hide');

        $("#message-content").html(
            "<div class='alert alert-error'>" +
            "<button class='close' data-dismiss='alert' type = 'button' >×</button >" +
            "<span>" +
            "You must include at least one item before clicking on Finish." +
            "</span>" +
            "</div >");
        return false;
    }

 $('#confirmation-modal').modal('hide');
 $('#modal-waiting').modal({
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: 'static'});
});
```

We do not go into the condition of if and so it proceeds in the submission of the form. 
The function takes a lot to give hide in the modal, as it enters the jquery and by the analysis of the diagnosis the jquery excerpt that presents delay is the one below:

```
    if (!(eventHandle = elemData.handle)) {
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function (e) {
                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== core_strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply(eventHandle.elem, arguments) :
                    undefined;
            };
            // Add elem as a property of the handle fn to prevent a memory leak with IE non-native events
            eventHandle.elem = elem;
        }
```

Follows the evidence of the performance report of the browser:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icXFy.png)

**Resolution: We submit the form via a native js submit**

Comment: If it's a `submit` have you tried to use the `on('submit')` handler instead of the `on('click')`?

Comment: the delay still continues on the form's submit...